# Is there any way to create new python API endpoints on the fly?

Tags: python, fastapi

I am just trying to figure out is there any way that one python script will create new endpoints or new python services on the fly, Like spawning new API endpoints from the script.

Some basic design will work! I just need some insights on how to do this design?

For a greater overview, let's say I have an application that creates an userId and the user provides some path for an endpoint that python app should generate a new API endpoint based on the path provided in the host, What should be the ideal way to do it?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can use `app.add_api_route('/foo', foo_route)` in FastAPI if necessary. However, there might be worth considering to use `APIRouter` and `include_router` instead, and you might want to have a plan about removing endpoints as well - using a dependency hierarchy might be a decent solution.

Answer (score 1):

so fastapi uses decorators to produce endpoints, and decorators are just syntax sugar where the decorator is function that takes in another function as input. with that you should just be able to apply the fastapi `get`/`post`/etc dynamically same way you would just apply a function dynamically

below is example how to apply decorator in way describe above

```
# Python code to illustrate
# Decorators with parameters in Python  (Multi-level Decorators)
 
def decodecorator(dataType, message1, message2):
    def decorator(fun):
        print(message1)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(message2)
            if all([type(arg) == dataType for arg in args]):
                return fun(*args, **kwargs)
            return "Invalid Input"
        return wrapper
    return decorator
 

def summation(*args):
    summ = 0
    for arg in args:
        summ += arg
    return summ

@decodecorator(int, "Decorator for 'summation'\n", "summation started ...")
def summation_with_decorator(*args):
    summ = 0
    for arg in args:
        summ += arg
    return summ

l = [19, 2, 8, 533, 67, 981, 119]
print(summation(*l))
print()
print(summation_with_decorator(*l))
print()
# applying decorator
summation = decodecorator(int, "Decorator for 'summation'\n", "summation started ...")(summation)
print(summation(*l))
```